# Segfault checking contents of first argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

Just having a bit of an issue here, I'm getting a seg fault *only in the last line of output* when the `argv[1] is -printable` but not when `argc == 1`. The only thing I can see being a problem is when I check `strcmp` it's assuming `argv[1]` exists. But when I change this I get the same problem; only the last line (from 120 - 126) is seg faulted. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
if((argc == 1) || strcmp(argv[1], "-printable")==0){
    for(i=LOWER;i<UPPER;i++){
        if((i-LIMIT)>=0){
            printf("%d %c  ", i, i);
        }else{
            printf("%d %c   ", i, i);
        }
        counter++;
        if(counter%LINE == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please try to select your question's topic and tags to be useful to others.

Comment: Can't you compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`) before asking such a simple question!!!! Using the debugger is *faster* than asking here!

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have some confusion with the following logic:

```
if ((argc == 1) || strcmp (argv[1], "-printable") == 0)
```

That really shouldn't segfault in a normal case since, if `argc` is any value greater than one, `argv[1]` should be a valid pointer. And, if it *is* set to one (no arguments), the second part of the expression (to the right of `||`) shouldn't be evaluated. This tends to suggest that either the code you've given isn't quite what you have, or the segfault is happening for another reason.

But, to be certain, I would inject the following code to check the values, before anything else in `main()`:

```
{
    int x;
    printf ("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (x = 0; x < argc; x++)
        printf ("argv[%d] = '%s'\n", x, argv[x]);
}
```

Normally, the intent is to simply execute the code if you provide `-printable` as the first argument and for that, you can use:

```
if ((argc > 1) && (strcmp (argv[1], "-printable") == 0))
```